# make menuconfig do not abbreviate options

Tags: gnu-make

Recently my `make menuconfig` has started only showing the first letter for the various options `Select`, `Exit`, `Help`, `Save`, `Load`

[image]

Worse, it seems that the `menuconfig` abbreviation is now system wide; other projects and previous commits are abbreviating the options as well. How do I prevent abbreviation?

Comment: Did you mess with the terminal colors and now have black on black?

Comment: @Jens maybe. If I unexport `MENUCONFIG_COLOR` the problem seems to go away. Right now I'm doing `export MENUCONFIG_COLOR=blackbg`.